# Azure B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am new to Azure AD B2C and am creating a custom policy.  When uploading TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml, I get an error stating that "An item with the same key has already been added." and the upload fails.

Any idea where I can start looking for this "key" and what the term "key" is referencing?

Comment: check under TechnicalProfile tag.

Comment: You could check the ```<Item>``` under ```<Metadata>``` of the Technical Profile. You might have a possible duplicate Key there.

Answer (score 0):

the key is a policy key.
you can find it your b2c tenant page. click on 'Identity Experience Framework' under security section. click on policy keys